# jkube resource failed: Unknown type CRD

Tags: jkube

I am using jkube to deploy a springboot helloworld application on my kubernetes installation. I wanted to add a resource fragment defining a Traefik ingress route but k8s:resource fails with **"Unknown type 'ingressroute'".**

IngressRoute has already been defined on the cluster using custom resource definition.

How do I write my fragment?

The following works when i deploy it with kubectl.

```
# IngresRoute
---
kind: IngressRoute
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: demo
  namespace: default

spec:
  entryPoints: 
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`demo.domainname.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: demo
      port: 80
```

Comment: Hello, Which version of Eclipse JKube are you using?

Comment: Using version 1.0.2.

Comment: I have provided an answer with recently released version v1.1.0. Could you please review and provide feedback if it's working for you?

Comment: If possible, Could you please provide a reproducer project which I can try out? If not, I can provide a project with your provided `IngressRoute` fragment which you can check to see what's missing in your configuration.

Comment: Sure. https://bitbucket.org/emercos/demo/src/master/

Comment: I was able to get it working with these changes:

`mv src/main/jkube/005-ingressroute.yml src/main/jkube/005-ingressroute-cr.yml` 
`mv src/main/jkube/002-tlsoption.yml src/main/jkube/002-tlsoption-cr.yml`

Comment: In case you still face problems, please reach out to us on our gitter channel: https://gitter.im/eclipse/jkube

Comment: It works all now! I can maven-build, push to docker, and deploy in my kubernetes baremetal cloud on Hetzner. Cool - thanks a lot Rohan. I would not have figured that solution out on my own.

Comment: Hi Rohan - were you able to re-apply without undeploy first ? It works fine if I re-apply using kubectl manually, but when running the k8s:apply target twice I get:
<pre>
..Failure executing: PUT at: https://168.119.233.19:6443/apis/traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/tlsoptions/quasifacttlsoption. Message: tlsoptions.traefik.containo.us "quasifacttlsoption" is invalid: metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: 0x0: must be specified for an update...
</pre>

Comment: oh, yeah. I was facing this too. Could you please create an issue on our Github repository?

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/jkube/issues/577
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will be fixed in our upcoming release(v1.2.0).

Comment: Hello, We have released v1.2.0. Would appreciate if you could try it out and provide feedback whenever you get time.

Comment: Hi Rohan - sorry for the delay. Yes, it works fine with 1.2.0. I can re-apply without undeploy first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying it out. Shall we close https://github.com/eclipse/jkube/issues/577 ?

Comment: Yes, problem solved. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Eclipse JKube team. We have improved CustomResource support a lot in our recent [v1.2.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jkube/kubernetes-maven-plugin/1.2.0/maven-plugin) release. Now you only need to worry about how you name your CustomResource fragment and Eclipse JKube would detect the CustomResourceDefinition for specified IngressRoute.

I think you would need to name CustomResource fragments with a `*-cr.yml` at the end. This is due to distinguishing them from standard Kubernetes resources. For example I added your `IngressRoute` fragment in my `src/main/jkube` like this:

```
jkube-custom-resource-fragments : $ ls src/main/jkube/
ats-crd.yml  crontab-crd.yml  dummy-cr.yml         podset-crd.yaml      traefic-crd.yaml
ats-cr.yml   crontab-cr.yml   ingressroute-cr.yml  second-dummy-cr.yml  traefic-ingressroute2-cr.yml
crd.yaml     dummy-crd.yml    istio-crd.yaml       test2-cr.yml         virtualservice-cr.yml
jkube-custom-resource-fragments : $ ls src/main/jkube/traefic-ingressroute2-cr.yml 
src/main/jkube/traefic-ingressroute2-cr.yml
```

Then you should be able to see your IngressRoute generated after `k8s:resource` phase:

```
$ mvn k8s:resource
...
$ cat target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes.yml
```

You can then go ahead and apply these generated manifests to your Kubernetes Cluster with apply goal:

```
$ mvn k8s:apply
...
$ kubectl get ingressroute
NAME   AGE
demo   17s
foo    16s
```

I tried all this on this reproducer project and it seemed to be working okay for me: https://github.com/r0haaaan/jkube-custom-resource-fragments

Answer (score 0):

@Rohan Kumar

Thank you for your answer. I can built and deploy it, but as soon as I add a file to use my IngressRoute, then the k8s:resource target fails.

I added files - one for each CRD with filename -cr.yml and added the following to the pom file:

```
<pre>
<resources>
    <customResourceDefinitions>
        <customResourceDefinition>traefikservices.traefik.containo.us</customResourceDefinition>
        <customResourceDefinition>tlsstores.traefik.containo.us</customResourceDefinition>
        <customResourceDefinition>tlsoptions.traefik.containo.us</customResourceDefinition>
        <customResourceDefinition>middlewares.traefik.containo.us</customResourceDefinition>
        <customResourceDefinition>ingressrouteudps.traefik.containo.us</customResourceDefinition>
        <customResourceDefinition>ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us</customResourceDefinition>
        <customResourceDefinitions>ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us</customResourceDefinitions>
    </customResourceDefinitions>
</resources>
```

Example IngressRoute definition:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: IngressRoute
    plural: ingressroutes
    singular: ingressroute
  scope: Namespaced
```

But when running the k8s:resource I get the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.0.2:resource (default-cli) on project demo:
Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.0.2:resource failed: Unknown type
'ingressroute' for file 005-ingressroute.yml. Must be one of : pr, lr, pv, project, replicaset, cronjob, ds,
statefulset, clusterrolebinding, pvc, limitrange, imagestreamtag, replicationcontroller, is, rb, rc, ingress, route,
projectrequest, job, rolebinding, rq, template, serviceaccount, bc, rs, rbr, role, pod, oauthclient, ns,
resourcequota, secret, persistemtvolumeclaim, istag, customerresourcedefinition, sa, persistentvolume, crb,
clusterrb, crd, deploymentconfig, configmap, deployment, imagestream, svc, rolebindingrestriction, cj, cm,
buildconfig, daemonset, cr, crole, pb, clusterrole, pd, policybinding, service, namespace, dc
```